# Как подключить библиотеку без примера android

Tags: android, git, gradle

Как правильно подключать склонированные библиотеки без примеров приложений?

Например, есть [следующая](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen/tree/master/material-intro-screen) библиотека. Я перехожу в папку с моей программой (Где у меня хранится build.gradle проекта) и используя команду `git clone * url *` клонирую библиотеку. Однако в нём есть ещё и пример обычного приложения, как мне от него избавиться? Просто удалить? Но как мне тогда делать `pull request`? Кроме того, что необходимо прописывать в файлах самого проекта, чтобы библиотека подключилась правильно? Для сборки проектов использую `Gradle`, в качестве клиента `Git`- `Git Bash`

Comment: https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen/blob/master/README.md Здесь есть пошаговое описание

Comment: @КириллМалышев можете показать где? Мне необходимо подключение **склонированной** библиотеки

Comment: Клонируйте в отдельный проект и подключайте нужный модуль к своему.